# writing a server that manages many clients

Tags: sockets

I'm new to designing a server software. I'd like to have the server decide which group the client belongs to, then give the client to the appropriate program to handle. For example, people connect to battle.net first, but then the server matches the players and then they start separate games.

But I see no way of doing this. When a socket connection is established, there are no ways I can give that socket object to another program. So the only way I can think of is to invoke another server and tell the client to reconnect to that one. Is that how it's usually done? Or is there some way I don't know of that can somehow transfer ownership of a socket to another program?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

1. Once client connects to the server. Client needs to send some request data which contains mapping information.
2. Server will parse this data and fork a new thread and call required function accordingly.
3. The server thread will return and the forked child will continue.
4. The function will handle this client and your main server can still listen to other clients request.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But this method is only good if the mapping routine is small, right? The forked thread would contain the mapping routine which is no longer needed for the dispatched client.

Comment: Yes that is absolutely true.. but this is the easiest approach. Some more robust approach might be possible but it needs an intermediate node. This node which will forward the request to appropriate server. For example we have a central server **A** and some other servers which handles different versions of games. The server "A" will act as Intermediate node between client and other server. This way we dont need to force user to connect to different server.